# How do I fix .lnk files on windows vista?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-registry, file-extension, sticky-notes

How do I fix .lnk files on windows vista? Sticky Notes and Windows Journal don't seem to work any more (apparently it's anything with a .lnk file extension). I already tried system restore, and even adding that "vistafix" registry thing and restarted my computer, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

A .lnk is a shortcut for a folder - this shortcut won't work unless the file you are linking to still exists. Right click on the shortcut and see if the "Target" file is still there. If it is not, the shortcut will not work until this file is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of shortcuts in Windows, .lnk and .url. These are both hidden most of the time, but any time either shortcut is broken it means something has changed, most likely the file moved or was deleted.

Also, don't do this:

```
and even adding that "vistafix" registry thing and restarted my computer,
```

If you don't know EXACTLY what you are doing the registry is a bad place to be. And with the complete lack of details I am scared for you.

What programs exactly where these shortcuts for? Specific files? Are the applications still installed?

Since the applications are missing, try this:

Open the startsearch and type and Launch Appwiz.cpl, In the left bar chose "Turn windows features on or off"

In the list that populates, verify "Tablet PC Components" is checked, if not check it.

See if your shortcuts for those applications is restored.

Comment: They were Sticky Notes, Tablet PC (4 links) and Windows Journal. I haven't deleted or uninstalled them though.

Comment: Can you still launch the applications at all?

Comment: Nope, and I don't know how to get to them besides those links in the start menu.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\StikyNot.exe for sticky notes and C:\Program Files\Windows Journal\Journal.exe for Windows Journal

Comment: Neither one is there ><

Comment: Next steps added at the end of my answer